# How to scrape this HTML structure with a tbody in Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, screen-scraping

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center table-condensed removeSidePadding" style="" xpath="1">
<thead class="success" style="padding: 15px; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;"></thead>
    <tbody style="">
      <tr class="active" data-index="0" style=""></tr>
      <tr data-index="1" style=""></tr>
      <tr class="active" data-index="2"></tr>
      <tr data-index="3"></tr>
      <tr class="active" data-index="4"></tr>
      <tr data-index="5"></tr>
      <tr class="active" data-index="6"></tr>
      <tr data-index="7"></tr>
      <tr class="active" data-index="8"></tr>
      <tr data-index="9"></tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

As for code to show, I do not have much to show except the boilerplate that Scrapy generates. I have been exclusively working within the shell just so I could pick these elements one by one but the problem I am running into is empty lists. I have done prior research and have found that scrapy will not pick up these tbody tags due to the browser generating them. (Currently using latest FireFox).

The data I want is within the tr tags and I think I can accomplish that later on but I am struggling with the elements before that.

I do have some progress on the parse method but once again I am constantly running into the issue of the tbody tag returning empty.

So ultimately how do I parse this?

```
    def parse(self, response):
    contents = response.xpath("//table[@id='myTable']")

    for content in contents:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL you are trying to scrap so I can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy wont find the `tbody` if it doesn't exist in the source page and are generated by the browser, but will select them perfectly if they are in the source. You can check by seeing the `response.body` that your scrapy gets in response.

Either way, it's just about to adjust the correct path.

If it the source doesn't use tbody:

```
response.xpath("//table[@id='myTable']/tr").getall()
```

If it does:

```
response.xpath("//table[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr").getall()
```

Comment: I ran both of these in my shell and they are still returning to me empty lists. Am I missing something? I forgot to add this in my original post but the content I am scraping is all JS generated but to address this I'm using scrapy_splash.